# Customizing WordPress theme (Twenty Thirteen). How to remove one title from the header without removing them all

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress theme and I want to edit the page where the title headers are located. (To be more specific, I am working on the'twenty thirteen' theme). Now, I only want to remove the title in the home page which says 'Home'. However, I cannot do that because that would remove all the titles in all the pages. So I have to make an if/else statement. The problem is nothing is working with me - pasted below is the code:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out function `the_title()` give you the page title. simply use this and put your html code between if block to customize it.

```
<?PHP if(the_title() === 'home' /* is_home() */): ?>
... <!-- your html -->
<?PHP endif; ?>
```

Comment: @SamerElSabeh Glad to hear dude! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the `is_home()` method.
Here is the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) to the method.

```
<header class="entry-header">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
<div class="entry-thumbnail">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif;if(!is_home()):?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></header><!-- .entry-header --><?php endif ?>
```

Comment: This also works. I've never used the is_home() function before. I am reading about it now. This is really helpful, I appreciate it.